# using 9.04 trying to install 16.04

Tags: mount, 16.04, iso

I have been trying to install 16.04 for two long days now. I need help. I dont really know what im doing since 9.04 is unsupported. I want to install 16.04 however I tried mounting the ISO and nothing happens.

EDIT: I installed rufus 2.9 and an error occured while loading the archive. I have a USB I could use, but I can't get a software to work properly.

EDIT #2: "Disk Image Writer" does not come up. I tried other options that seemed similar but all had an "error". If it helps I installed this ubuntu 9.04 from a CD. I do not have any other blank CDs but I do have a 64GB flash drive.

Comment: You do not mount the iso to install Ubuntu. You need to burn it to a disc and boot your computer from that. Alternatively you could also write the iso to an USB drive and boot from that.

Comment: You can use the gnome image writer: right-click on the ISO file and select "open with > disk image writer". Then let it write that onto your USB device (data on USB will be deleted!).

Answer (score 0):

As update from 9.04 to 16.04 is not supported and you don't have any other blank DVD available, the only way is to do a clean install from usb. In my opinion the easiest way is to download the latest `startup disk creator` from launchpad because you will probably get errors if you use unetbooin in your old os.

- So download and install the packages `usb-creator-common` and `usb-creator-gtk` (amd64 or i386 depending or your architecture) from this link under the section `Binary packages`: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/usb-creator

Let me know if you have any package dependencies errors. If not, you should be able to create your live ubuntu usb and do a clean install.

Comment: I can not find where to download them. If i did download them I get an error after Package Installer opens and it says " Could not open 'usb-creator-common_0.3.2_amd64.deb" :(((((